# WPF - Update Data Service

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I am hoping this is not as open a question as it seems to me.  Currently we have a WPF application that has its own data objects that we load data into from an SQL database using entity framework. We do not bind our ViewModel or UI to the entity framework objects.

My question is what is the recommended way to make the application aware of data changes?

Comment: Have your view-model observe changes in your model (entity framework objects) and then report such changes to the UI. Make sure the view-model implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and that properties that need to be reported raise `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` whenever their values change.

Comment: To use this approach and not to force the collection to be an `ObservableColelction` you need to use `CollectionViewSource` in your xaml to make the UI pick up the changes for separate entities. HTH